# Font Flickering on First load in Next js with Fountsource and Material Ui?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, font-face, google-fonts

I am building one `Next.js` applications. For styling I am using `Material-ui`. I am using [`Inter`](https://fontsource.org/fonts/inter) font from `FontSource`.

I am facing one flickering problem in this site-
[image]

I can't understand why I am seeing this type of flicker?

This is the live url- https://hardjourney.vercel.app/login

Here is my code example-

I install `@fontsource/inter` this and just call it in my `_app.tsx`-

```
//Fonts
import "@fontsource/inter/300.css";
import "@fontsource/inter/400.css";
import "@fontsource/inter/500.css";
import "@fontsource/inter/600.css";
import "@fontsource/inter/700.css";
```

And then I add this in Material-ui theme-

```
const theme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: "Inter"
    }
});
export default theme;
```

Font working but problem it the site load first time without font and then load fonts. What is the problem Where I have to change in my applications. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the font-display to auto helped in my case